# $_ in bash vs. dash scripts

Tags: bash, debian, sh

I need to port a short script from `bash` to `dash` (i.e. `sh` under Debian 10). It contains the following line:

```
chown root:www-data /etc/nginx/conf.d && chmod 775 $_
```

This now fails because `$_` held the previous command's last argument (i.e. `/etc/nginx/conf.d`) with `bash` but now holds a different value with non-interactive `dash`. As another case in point, outputs from `bash -c 'echo 1 2 && echo $_'` and `dash -c 'echo 1 2 && echo $_'` also differ.

What is a typical way for forming "concise" statements of the above type in `dash` (without resorting to more specialized commands, such as `install`)?

Comment: [`$_` is not a POSIX standard.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129272/where-is-defined-by-posix). So do not use it in scripts, which should be portable.

Comment: Ideally, there'd be a single command that let you change both the owner and the mode of a file. `chstuff --owner root:www-data --mode 775 /etc/nginx.conf.d`. Both `chown` and `chmod` are essentially just wrappers around system calls. (And before any one raises the "Unix philosophy" argument that a tool should do one thing, `chown` already let's you change the group as well instead of having to run `chgrp` separately.)

Comment: Depending on how `/etc/nginx/conf.d` is created in the first place, there may be options for setting the owner and mode at that time (cf `install`).

Comment: @chepner `install` can be that command. (It's non-atomic, of course.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write a function.

```
chownmod () { chown "$1" "$3" && chmod "$2" "$3"; }
```

And replace the line with the following.

```
chownmod root:www-data 775 /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Comment: Yep, that's a clean solution. I'll go for that (unless another, very concise alternative comes up.)

Answer (score 0):

Just define an explicit variable to hold the directory name.

```
d=/etc/nginx/conf.d
chown root:www-data "$d" && chmod 755 "$d"
```

`$_` is intended as an interactive shortcut. A script, written with the help of an editor, doesn't really need such shortcuts.

Comment: "doesn't really need ...": Beauty (also as in a concise expression that serves well) is in the eye of the beholder :)